# How can I confirm a cffile write is successful?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cffile

I am using cffile to create a new file or update an existing file, depending on what the user requested. The request comes through a form from the previous procedure, so the code involving cffile looks like this:

```
<cfset thefile = "#form.dyn#">
<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent variable = "testvar">
  #form.editor1#
</cfsavecontent>     
<cffile action = "write"
    file   = "/var/www/reports/#thefile#.cfm"
    output = "#testvar#">
</cfoutput>
```

When I am done writing to the file, I want to confirm to the user that this happened.  For a new file I could use IsDefined to check that it is there.  But I can't think of a way to check for an existing file that was updated.  I considered a try/catch on the cffile, but the catch operates only if nothing seems to go wrong.  If I don't get an error on the catch, can I assume everything is all right? I would prefer a direct check if possible.  Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Re *use IsDefined to check that it is there*. No, that is only for variables. For files, use `FileExists` -or- [`GetFileInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d02.html) for existing files (CF9+). Though this seems like overkill. If the `cffile` action fails, CF will throw an error and you can take action in the `cfcatch` clause.

Comment: Thanks Leigh for enlightening me about the FileExists or GetFileInfo. Guess I would have found this out if I had tried IsDefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [cfdirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f99.html) with the `action="list"` and `filter="your-filename"` to get the following information about the uploaded file:

> If action = "list", cfdirectory returns the following result columns, which you can reference in a cfoutput tag:
>
> - name: Directory entry name. The entries "." and ".." are not returned.
> - directory: Directory that contains the entry.
> - size: Directory entry size.
> - type: File type: file, for a file; dir, for a directory.
> - dateLastModified: The date that an entry was last modified.
> - attributes: File attributes, if applicable.
> - mode: Empty column; retained for backward compatibility with ColdFusion 5 applications on UNIX.

Of interest to you is the `dateLastModified` column.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" name="dirQuery" directory="C:/var/www/reports/" filter="#thefile#.cfm">
```

Then you can dump that result to see what information is available to you:

```
<cfdump var="#dirQuery#">
```

The `dateLastModified` column can be accessed like:

```
<cfoutput>#dirQuery.dateLastModified#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: very helpful -- exactly what I want.

Comment: @BettyMock - If this worked for you then please select it as the answer so that others can find it more easily in the future.

Answer (score 5):

If `<cffile>` doesn't work, it'll tell you by throwing an exception. If it doesn't do that, you can safely assume it has worked. Don't over-engineer your app.

Comment: Of course, one must be clear about what "over-engineer" means.  I am expecting helpless users, so I have to protect them to the extent possible.

Comment: "Over-engineer" in this case is "writing unnecessary code" which is what you'd be doing if you wrote any more than zero code to deal with this. You are trying to solve an issue that is already dealt with for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [CFDirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f99.html) to get the file's `dateLastModified` before you update the file and then again afterwards. If they are not the same, then it was updated.